# User.Identity.Name sometimes blank with Windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, windows-authentication

My web app uses Windows authentication. All other authentication methods are disabled.

It works at first; User.Identity.Name returns "MYDOMAIN\myuser." However, if I wait 131 seconds (yes, I timed it, though I'm not sure it always takes exactly that long) and reload the page, User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = false and User.Identity.Name = "". At this point I can just reload the page and it works again, for another 131 seconds of inactivity.

Relevant parts of web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization> 
  <deny users="?" /> 
</authorization>
<identity impersonate="false" />
...
<security>
  <authentication>
    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
  </authentication>
</security>
```

More information, possibly relevant:

My solution is deployed to two different IIS applications. The first one is for internal users; it just uses Windows authentication. The second one is for external users; it uses anonymous authentication (in the root folder only) and forms authentication. I'm only having problems with the internal site.

Comment: It would might be helpful to be able to see your `<configuration><system.web><membership>` section and any applicable `<connectionStrings>` elements.  Also am I crazy or is there no such thing as a `<security>` element in `<system.web>`?

Comment: I do not have a membership section in system.web. The security element is actually under system.webserver. The connection string is     <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=XXXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXXX;User ID=XXX;Password=XXX" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />.

Answer (score 1):

The web.config file under the Account folder was allowing anonymous authentication (the one I posted with my question is the main web.config). Not sure how that happened, but removing it fixed the problem.